# Pandas Sort, Groupby and running difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

i have just started using Pandas and i'm amazed by how flexible it is but i've hit a roadblock and need some help

I have a Data frame Df:

```
| Contract | Year | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | 
| A        | 2020 | 90   |  95. |  100 | 
|A         | 2019 | 80   |   85.|    90|
|A         | 2018 |  75. |  70. |   80 |
|  B       |2020  | 90.  | 95.  | 100  |
|  B       |  2019|  80  |   85.|   90 |
|  B       |2018 |  75.  |  70. |  80  |
```

I wanted to find row wise running difference for Val1,Val2,Val3 after grouping the data on contract and sorting the data on contract and year so that the output looks something like:

Output:

```
| Contract|  Year |  Val1  | Val2 |  Val3 |
|  A      | 2020  | 10     |10.   | 10    |
| A       | 2019  |5       |15.   | 10    |
|A        |2018   |NaN     | NaN  |   NaN |
| B       |2020   |10.     | 10.  |   10  | 
| B       |2019   |5       |15.   |  10.  |
|B        | 2018  | NaN   | NaN   |  NaN  |
```

I tried doing this using the sort groupby and diff in Pandas but i'm not getting the right output:

Code i tried:

Df.sort_values(['Contract','Year'],ascending=False).groupby(['Contract']).diff()

This doesn't include Contract and year in the output. Where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, after the `.sort_values` you can do:

```py
df.loc[:, "Val1":"Val3"] = df.groupby(df["Contract"]).diff().mul(-1).shift(-1)
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  Contract  Year  Val1  Val2  Val3
3        B  2020  10.0  10.0  10.0
4        B  2019   5.0  15.0  10.0
5        B  2018   NaN   NaN   NaN
0        A  2020  10.0  10.0  10.0
1        A  2019   5.0  15.0  10.0
2        A  2018   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answers, if i were to find out percent change how can i do it, can you please help me there as well.

Comment: @VikasYadav Please open a new question here on StackOverflow. I try to look at it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrej, i've posted the question here : https://stackoverflow.com/q/72949285/11671772