# Pandas Sort,Group running difference percent

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, group-by

1

i have just started using Pandas and i'm amazed by how flexible it is but i've hit a roadblock and need some help

I have a Data frame Df:

```
| Contract | Year | Val1 | Val2 | Val3 | 
| A        | 2020 | 90   |  95. |  100 | 
|A         | 2019 | 80   |   85.|    90|
|A         | 2018 |  75. |  70. |   80 |
|  B       |2020  | 90.  | 95.  | 100  |
|  B       |  2019|  80  |   85.|   90 |
|  B       |2018 |  75.  |  70. |  80  |
```

I wanted to find row wise running difference for Val1,Val2,Val3 after grouping the data on contract and sorting the data on contract and year so that the output looks something like:

Output:

```
| Contract|  Year |  Val1  | Val2 |  Val3 |

|  A      | 2020  | (10/80)|(10/95)|(10/90)|

| A       | 2019  |(5/75)  |(15/70)|(10/80)|

|A        |2018   |NaN     | NaN  |   NaN  |

| B       |2020   |(10/80) |(10/85)| (10/90| 

| B       |2019   |(5/75)  |(15/70)|(10/80)|

|B        | 2018  | NaN   | NaN   |  NaN  |
```

I tried doing this using the sort groupby and diff in Pandas but i'm not getting the right output:

Code i tried:

```
df.loc[:, "Val1":"Val3"] = (df.groupby(df["Contract"]).diff().mul(-1).shift(-1)/ 
                            df.groupby(df["Contract"]).shift(-1))
```

This doesn't include Contract and year in the output. Where i'm going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Contract":["A","A","A","B","B","B"],
    "Year":[2020,2019,2018,2020,2019,2018],
    "Val1":[90,80,75,90,80,75],
    "Val2":[95,85,70,95,85,70],
    "Val3":[100,90,80,100,90,80]
})
df
```

[image]
Assume:

- `Year` is in **Descending order**

**Pandas** has built-in function called `pct_change`

```
df2 = df.groupby(['Contract'])[['Val1','Val2','Val3']].pct_change(periods=-1)
df2
```

[image]

If you wanna assign the result back to `df` and overwrite the original values of `Val1`, `Val2`, `Val3`

```
df[['Val1','Val2','Val3']] = df2
df
```

[image]